# Salesforce Triggers | Custom Settings

Tags: app-development

Could any one please elaborate, how we can run a trigger according to a user. I heard it from some friends, that we can call trigger in respect to users with the help of Custom settings, could any one will give an example in Simple | Understandable language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is someone else's answer but here is a 2015 article on the topic. See the "Triggers" portion. https://www.absi.digital/en/Articles/Dev-Zone/personalize-automation-salesforce

Comment: Thanks Peter, Should I create a list type custom settings or hierarchy type ?

Comment: hierarchy because sounds like you need user-specific settings and hierarchy supports that

Answer (score 0):

Store list of user details like user id , name on the custom settings. Then use that custom setting inside trigger to validate based on the current user is in the list or not.